# Reboot always stops on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, reboot

Ubuntu always stops for ten minutes on reboot. Server Dell Precision.
Other Ubuntu Versions are running without a problem and are rebooting on the same server. It seems to be a problem with syslog...  Also I have the same probleme doing apt-get upgrade - the process is interrupted for 10 minutes.

```
entries in syslog:
Sep 22 16:40:26 petrus systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Sep 22 16:40:26 petrus systemd[1]: Unmounted /var/lib/lxcfs.
Sep 22 16:40:26 petrus rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="933" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="946" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus systemd-modules-load[401]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus loadkeys[396]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Sep 22 16:50:36 petrus systemd-modules-load[401]: Inserted module 'ib_iser'
```

What can I do to get this problem solved? Thank's for helping....

Greetings
Joe